# How to debug a Python script that segfaults when run as a systemd?

Tags: python, uwsgi, archlinux, systemd

This is driving me nuts.

A Flask app works fine if i personally run uWSGI from the CLI:

```
uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
```

but when trying to start it as a service with systemd, there is a segfault and the resulting coredump says almost nothing:

```
sudo systemctl start emperor.uwsgi
```

coredump:

```
[New LWP 7639]
Core was generated by `/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini website.ini'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000123c in ?? ()
```

So, I have no idea how to get more detailed information. This is not a script I'm running with Python app.py, but is a script being served by uWSGI.

I'm clueless and would appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Edit I - systemd init script:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT $MAINPID
Restart=always
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
KillSignal=SIGQUIT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If i run `/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini` manually, works fine.

Comment: It would help to see your `systemd` script [for the `emperor.uwsgi` service]. Note that you manually start with `uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini` but the segfault comes from `/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini website.ini`. So, does that make a difference? Can you post all the relevant files?

Comment: Have you tried different Python versions/environments?

Comment: @CraigEstey hi, added the systemd init. Everything i run in the CLI makes the web app work. /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini website.ini is not a valid command as the absolute path to website.ini is not that, but that must be something related to emperor mode.

Comment: @AnthonyE hi. No, but i did try with simpler Python scripts (a 'hello world' for example) in the same python virtualenv and worked fine.